# How can I configure which xcodebuild tool version is run when running react-native run ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After upgrading to Xcode 12, I discovered a project dependency in my larger react-native workspace needs some work to address unsupported architectures.

Until then, I want to continue working on the react-native app, so I installed Xcode 11.7 side-by-side with Xcode 12.

This works fine unless I try to start the app via the CLI tool. It appears the project is still being built by Xcode 12 (the same unsupported architecture errors I saw at compile time are output to the terminal).

`which xcodebuild` points to /usr/bin/xcodebuild.

What do I need to modify to have version 11.7 run the build command instead of version 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xcode-select` command to determine at which Xcode version's command line tools the `xcodebuild` points to:

```
~ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

You can change the selected Xcode version using `-s` option:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/PathToXcode11/Xcode.app
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.